# No figure showing on window in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a Macbook Pro 2018. The problem is that the figure does not show up in the window produced by the matplotlib.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

This is the result.
[image: The result is this]

I've also changed the backend of the .matplotlibrc
[image: Add TkAgg in .matplotlibrc]

What could be missing?

Comment: Try Minimizing all the open windows, terminals, browser etc. It happened with me that the figure window went in the background

Comment: Seems to be a backend problem. Using Qt5 I get the expected result

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe the matplotlibrc file is not the one that is taken into account? Can you try setting the backend within the code itself: In the first line add `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried it. Still getting the same results.
I installed matplotlib via pip in a virtualenv.

Comment: Did you read [Working with Matplotlib on OSX](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html)?

Comment: I just read it now. I tried changing the PYTHONPATH to point it to my virtualenv like so: 
`export PYTHONPATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:/$PATH/usr/lib/python2.7:$PATH"`

Still getting the same result. Maybe it's because I had 2 python versions installed in my systems? Python 2.7 and Python 3.5? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: That document says *"The solution is to not use virtualenv, but instead the stdlib's venv, which provides similar functionality but without exhibiting this issue.

If you absolutely need to use virtualenv rather than venv, then from within the environment you can set the PYTHONHOME environment variable to $VIRTUAL_ENV, then invoke Python using the full path to the framework build (typically /usr/local/bin/python)."* I have never tried that out myself, because I have never used a mac for more than 5 minutes in my life.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This worked in my other mac though. Not sure why it wouldn't work now.